# ShowModalDialog problem in Bricscad v23 using .net and vs2022

Tags: .net, debugging, autocad-plugin, bricscad

I'm migrating a plugin from Autocad to Bricscad.
I'm using .net, vs2022 and Bricscad v23.

I have a command with the next code:

```
FrmMyForm frm = new FrmMyForm()
{
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
};
DialogResult result = _ApplicationServices.Application.ShowModalDialog(frm);
```

Inside the form I have one button and it's working correctly...but only in release configuration.

If I try to run vs in debug mode and then I attach to the bricscad process, I can not access to the code of the event click of the button.
I always receive the same message in vs:
**The application is in break mode**

Any idea how to avoid this problem?

I tried to change some parameter in the options of vs but not good results.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in other chat
[Breakpoints in custom form...](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/12/breakpoints-in-custom-form-not-hit-when-debugging-net-addin-for-autocad-2012-from-visual-studio-2010.html?cid=6a0167607c2431970b017d3ef484d1970c)

In my case I fixed it changing the variable NEXTFIBERWORLD from 1 to 0